# Responsive Datatables (different approach)

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, datatables

I am working on a web app which has Datatables (tabular structure) everywhere..

I want this app to work on Desktop, Tablet and Mobile Phones.. Unfortunately there is no solid method of doing this.. I have googled and found many articles on making it responsive but unfortunately none of them makes shows it the way I want..

Here is the structure I am looking for (it has to be like this for some obvious reasons)..

1. On Desktop

[image]

2. On Tablets

[image]

3. On Mobile

[image]

**<<** and **>>** are handlers which will move visible columns. I am unable to find efficient way of doing this. Any idea how can I make it?

Comment: what problems are you encountering? What have you tried? CSS media queries will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Suggest you at least create a starting point in html demo

Comment: https://github.com/Comanche/datatables-responsive